# Is there any library of C++ to get acceleration data of android phone via Bluetooth?

Tags: android, c++, visual-c++, bluetooth

I'd like to develop an application on Visual C++ that receives acceleration data of an android phone. From what I've found out, there is any way to send such data from android phone via Bluetooth, but I'm not sure how to get the data on PC, especially on Visual C++. Is there any library or some API to receive data from android phone via Bluetooth?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

No built-in application on Android shares such data over Bluetooth by default. You're going to have to write an Android app for that.

In this case the data transfer would happen over Bluetooth serial port connection. You can write an application to receive that data on your platform and language of choice. I'm unsure on how to do that with VC.

To answer your question formally: there is no library to do what you want out of the box, as one would have to incorporate an application that runs on the target device.